# Close integer solutions to $ab-cd=1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms, diophantine-approximation

I am looking for infinite set of Diophantine solutions.

1. Suppose we require
   $$0<\min(a,d)<\max(a,d)<\min(b,c)<\max(b,c)\leq\sqrt 2\min(a,d)$$
   $$a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Z$$
   then can we still find solutions to
   $$ab-cd=1?$$
2. Is it possible to do this if only
   $$a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Z$$
   $$0<\min(a,d)<\max(a,d)<\min(b,c)<\max(b,c)$$
   $$ad<ab+cd\leq2ad\leq2bc$$ holds?
3. If not what is the closest permissible?

What is a good bound?

Comment: Note 2. is not necessarily weaker and is a different statement if $ab+cd<bc$ does not hold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible with any constant $\lambda>1$ on the place of $\sqrt{2}$. Take $a=t^2$, $d=t^2+t-1$, $b=t^2+2t+1$, $c=t^2+t+1$ for large $t$.

Comment: nicely done!...

Comment: @FedorPetrov Is it also possible to do 2. or at least do it with a different example? In your example $ab+cd<bc$ does not hold.

Comment: @VS. I am confused, what exact conditions do you require now? I thought that 2. is $ad<ab+cd\leqslant 2ad$ which clearly holds for this example.

Comment: 2. is impossible. Assume $b=d+\delta_1$ and $c=a+\delta_2$. Then $ab+cd=2ad+a\delta_1+d\delta_2$ and since $\max(b,c)\leq\min(a,d)$ we have $\delta_1,\delta_2>0$.